# Foreach on a form using multiple models on one view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm using a database with FK, PK. I wanted to make a form using 2 tables, both have their proper relationship etc.

**Tables:**

```
User : ID (PK), Name, Company (FK)
Company: ID(PK), Name
```

Its a form where the user put is name and I wanted to make a dropdown list where he retrieves the Company.Name instead of the ID.

Here is the **form**:

```
    @model User_rel

<form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input asp-for="User.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="pessoa.Nome" class="text-danger" />
        <label asp-for="Company.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Company *</label>
        <select name="empresa">
    @foreach (User test in Model.user)
    {
        <option value="@Model.company.ID">@Model.company.Name</option>
    }
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
```

These are my **models**

```
public class User_rel
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Company company { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
     public int ID{get;set;}
     public string User{get;set;}
     public int Company_rel{get;set;}
}
```

And here is the **controller**

```
 public IActionResult Create()
 {
        return View();
 }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string empresa, [Bind("Name, Company_rel")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("USER_SET @p0, @p1", parameters: new Object[] { user.Name, user.Company_rel });
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Already a lot of times and followed huge amount of tutorials but it didn't worked.

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'RTM_MVC.Models.User' because 'RTM_MVC.Models.User' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I tried to put the GetEnumerator<> on the User Model but didnt worked...

Comment: Is there more to the HTML code that you're not showing? Because what you're showing doesn't show a `foreach` over a `User`, but over  `Model.pessoa`, which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Oh my bad @MikeMcCaughan already changed!

Comment: Well, `model.user` is a _single_ user, so `foreach` is not appropriate.  Are you intending to show _multiple_ users on the form? Then your property should be an `IEnumerable<User>` instead

Comment: What does your DbContext look like? and @DStanley is correct on the user being a single entity. Also, can your users be related to more than one company?